# STED Microscopy: Differentiate between emission from stimulated emission and fluorescence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, microscopy

From what I understand about stimulated emission in STED microscopy, a red shifted Laser (apperently with a wavelength around the emission wavelength of the fluorophor) is used to induce stimulated emission.
The photon released in that process is of the same wavelength as the STED-Laser, so as well around the emission wavelength.

Now to the question:
If stimulated emission and fluorescence emission have very similar wavelengths, how can you differentiate between actual fluorescence and stimulated emission?
Is there a wavelength-difference after all which can be exploited with an emission filter?

Comment: See https://www.picoquant.com/applications/category/life-science/sted for example

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is still a difference in wavelength.

The same excitation level is generally represented (i.e after excitation you lose a bit of energy to a more stable excited state). From this excitated state stimulated emission usually reach a high energy ground state, while fluorescence reach a lower energy ground state. Moreover, I think the stimulated emission has an energy linked to the depletion laser, so a fixed wavelength. Thus you can separate both emission with a dichroic, and use a filter that would precisely remove the wavelength linked to depletion (stimulation). You could also perform some time gated detection as both process do not have the same duration.

Disclaimer : I am not an expert in STED

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).